# Unity Разместить UI image в центре родительского элемента

Tags: unity3d, изображения, ui

На Canvas повешен дочерний объект, в этом дочернем объекте я хочу создать UI Image через скрипты. Я смог отобразить картинку, но мне нужно поставить ее в произвольную точку экрана и чтобы она имела, например, 10% ширины от родителя. Как сделать это корректно, чтобы Image не съезжал и не искажался при смене разрешения? Можете дать пример, например, в центр поставить его?

Comment: Не подскажете, с какой целью вам это нужно? Возможно, уже есть готовые решения прямо в unity. Хотите какой-то список кнопок создать? Несколько строчек из картинок-кнопок уровней?

Comment: Я уже решил проблему. Просто я думал, что нужно anchors выставлять, но потом дошло, что разрешение, во-первых, не меняется на одном смартфоне, а во-вторых, можно просто в update перерасчет сделать если нужно. А как программно выставить anchors в зависимости от позиции и размеров родителя, его пивота и прочего прочего, я уже, похоже, даже не догадываюсь. UI система в Юнити сделана отвратительно.

Comment: якоря и прочее в Unity есть только у `RectTransform` - элементов, находящихся внутри `Canvas`, а у `MonoBehaviour` кешируется его родитель общий для всех объектов - обычный `Transform`. Поэтому прежде, чем что-то менять у объекта нужно его `.transform` привести к `RectTransform`. `var rect = transform as RectTransform;` и вот уже у этого `rect` будут все нужные вам поля